# Cross-browser solution for detecting text input change, including copy and paste into the field?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser, jquery-events

I started using `$('#myInput').bind('input', function() {` but this does not work in IE.

What is the best cross-browser solution to detect any change to a text input field, including if the user copy and pastes into the field?

Comment: I'd test an idea, but I don't want to have to open Internet Explorer in order to do so.

Comment: use propertychange for IE http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Intevals.

They are ugly. Unnecessary. Hated by virtually everyone. But one of the few and by far the most resilient way of testing for user input on IE.

**Reasons:**

- `.on('input', function(){})` isn't supported in IE<9, and is buggy in IE9-10 - it doesn't fire when characters are deleted.
- `keyup` is far from perfect, you can paste from right-click menu and toolbar.
- The `paste` event is well supported since IE6 as far as I remember, but then keyboard input and pasting aren't the only ways of inputting values. You can select, drag and drop text in an input too. This is one of the reasons why intervals are preferred when implementing IE support.

In IE you can also have [`onpropertychange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as a fallback, but then it will fire whenever an object property changes, forcing you to do similar "value changed" validation as you would with an Interval. Thus I'd rather write a single interval that works in all browsers than writing a code for all browsers and another for IE.

So my suggested solutions are:

1. Use an interval as follows:

   ```
   $(function() {
       var input = $('#foo'); //change this selector to your input
       function checkchange() {
           var v = input.val();
           if (input.data('v') === v) return;
           input.data('v', v);
           //do stuff
       }
       input.data('v', input.val());
       setInterval(checkchange, 100);
   });
   ```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/33Mtf/1/)

Or 2. Put [GCF](https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/) on a modal and hide the X button, therefore forcing IE users to install it and you'll never have to write IE-specific code again - I do this whenever I can! Then again, my target audience usually doesn't include IE users.

Comment: CGF isn't really a good option for me on this project.  I went with using keyup as I normally do, seeing as already have robust server-side validation in place already.  So although detecting copy and paste would be nice for UI enhancement, it doesn't really matter if someone tries that.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes I do `.on('input keyup paste change', function(){})` then check if the value was changed as in my interval above and `return` the handler in case it didn't change.